# MFMailCompose issues with iPhone5

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a new way to present a MFMailComposeViewController for the iPhone 5? I'm working with a 4 and 5 side by side and the 4 presents/works correctly, yet for the 5 it doesn't even hit the code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@myemail.com"]];
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"Feedback"];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    [mailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it works perfect for me on iPhone 5!

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [MFMailComposeViewController mailComposeViewControllerWithRecipe:self.recipe];
if (mailVC) {
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:mailVC animated:YES];
}
```

what exactly do you mean "it doesn't even hit the code"? Maybe yours

```
([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
```

is false or problem in some abother place

Comment: indeedly, ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) is false on the 5. Weird? Just curious if I'm the only one with this oddness O_o

Comment: Maybe just try to setup at leas one email.app account?

Comment: yeeeup. I didn't set up the 5 with an email account. Awesome. Thanks iiFreeman ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is your mail set up for the iPhone5?

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I ran into this a few times with some development phones that weren't hooked up to an account. Hopefully this will help someone.